# Can we use free logic structures to define Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games in languages with function symbols?

Tags: logic, model-theory

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game#Definition) is the definition of an Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game from Wikipedia. I like this definition because it's easy to visualize building structures on top of the index set for the moves of the game $\{1, \cdots, n\}$ in order to check who won the game. It also keeps the structures we're comparing finite in cases where the game has finitely many turns. I don't know whether that property is important, but it seems nice intuitively.

This definition has the drawback, however, of not handling function symbols at all.

I'm wondering whether we can solve this problem by looking at structures in a *simple free logic* and if what we get lines up with the *standard definition of an Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game*.

**Let's only consider free logic structure whose relations return false whenever any of their arguments are $c^*$. Suppose we allows Spoiler and Duplicator to pick terms in the *full domain of free logic* (defined in Appendix A) and allow each player a free move of $c^*$ at the beginning of the game. Does it hold that Spoiler wins the *Free Logic Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé Game* if and only if Spoiler wins the corresponding Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé Game?**

---

##### Wikipedia Definition of Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé Game

Unfortunately, I can't tell from the Wikipedia article what source was used for this definition.

> Suppose we are given two structures $A$ and $B$, each with no function symbols and the same set of relation symbols and a fixed natural number $n$. We can then define the Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game $G_n(A, B)$ to be the game between two players, Spoiler and Duplicator, played as follows:
>
> 1. The first player, Spoiler, picks either a member $a_1$ of $A$ or a member $b_1$ or $B$.
> 2. If spoiler picks a member of $A$, Duplicator picks a member $b_1$ of $B$; otherwise Duplicator picks a member $a_1$ of $A$.
> 3. Spoiler picks either a member $a_2$ of $A$ or a member $b_2$ of $B$.
> 4. Duplicator picks an element $a_2$ or $b_2$ from the model which Spoiler did not pick.
> 5. Spoiler and Duplicator continue to pick members of $A$ and $B$ for $n-2$ more steps.
> 6. At the conclusion of the game, we have chosen distinct elements $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ of $A$ and $b_1, \cdots, b_n$ of $B$ therefore we have two structures on the set $\{1, \cdots, n\}$, one induced from $A$ via the map sending $i$ to $A$, and the other induced from $B$ via the map sending $i$ to $b_i$. Duplicator wins if these structures are the same, Spoiler wins if they are not.

By looking at the definition, it's clear what the assumption prohibiting function symbols is doing. In other definitions of EF games, the structures that we compare at the end of the game are substructures in $A$ or $B$ generated by the sequence of moves in their respective structure. For example, Hodges takes this approach in *A Shorter Model Theory* on pages 74 and 75.

---

##### Semantics For The Specific Flavor of Free Logic Being Considered

[Free logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/) is a family of variations of first-order logic. These logics allow constants that don't refer to anything and partial functions.

Let $M$ be a free logic model. $M$ had a disjoint outer domain $D^o$ and inner domain $D^i$. $D^{oi}$ refers to their union, the full domain. $D^o$ is constrained to be a singleton. The logical symbols for free logic are the same as for FOL with the addition of $c^*$, a symbol designating the sole element of the outer domain $D^o$.

$v$, the variables, take values in the full domain $D^{oi}$.

$ M, v \models t_1 = t_2 $ holds if and only if the interpretation of $t_1$ in $D^{oi}$ is the same as the interpretation of $t_2$ in $D^{oi}$. Note that the interpretation of $c^*$ is the sole element of $D^o$. Also, the interpretation of $f(\cdots c^* \cdots)$ is the interpretation of $c^*$.

$M, v \models R(t_1, \cdots, t_n)$ holds if and only if $\langle t_1, \cdots t_n \rangle$ is in $[\![R]\!]$. Note that $[\![R]\!]$ is a subset of $(D^{oi})^n$ where $n$ is the arity of $R$.

$ M, v \models \lnot \varphi $ holds if and only if $M, v \not\models \varphi$.

$ M, v \models \varphi \land \psi$ holds if and only if $M, v \models \varphi$ and $M, v \models \psi$.

$M, v \models \exists x \mathop. \varphi(x)$ if and only if there exists a constant $c$ in $D^i$ such that $M, v \models \varphi(c)$.

As a structure, constants in $M$ get values in the full domain. Functions are in $(D^{oi})^n \to D^{oi}$ but are constrained to return $c^*$ if any of their arguments are $c^*$. Relations are subsets of $(D^{oi})^n$.

Comment: You can also replace any function symbol $f$ by a predicate $G_f$ that corresponds to the graph of $f$.

Comment: Why do you want the $c^*$ element versus just playing the game on the terms of the original logic? What is making sure that if $x$ gets matched to $y$ then $f(x)$ gets matched to $f(y)$?

Comment: @TomKern I'm sorta confused. I don't think it changes the free logic EF game to  permit $c^*$ or not as a legal move. The freebie $c^*$ element is there at the beginning to avoid skewing the turn numbers. (Incidentally, I don't think it works, I suspect that the generate-a-substructure approach used by Hodges causes Spoiler victories to "happen earlier" than in the approach outlined in the question)